# ssh tunnel through an intermediate host

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have configured an SSH tunnel to forward my web traffic from hostA to hostC using this command on hostA:

```
    ssh -D 2222 user@hostC
```

after configuring my browser to use a proxy on port 2222. This works great. However, I now want to forward the same traffic through an intermediate SSH connection on hostB in order to get to hostC.

I tried this on hostA:

```
    ssh user@hostB -L 2222:hostB:22
```

but I get "channel x: open failed" errors.
Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

On hostA:

```
ssh -L8080:localhost:22222 user@hostB
```

On hostB:

```
ssh -D22222 user@hostC
```

Then on hostA you can use `localhost:8080` as SOCKS5 proxy.